# How to replace words from a String if it contains any word from my String array

Tags: java, android

I want to replace words that matches with any one in my String array,i tried the code below but it's only replacing the first condition, i believe its because of the return statement but i can't figure out another way to do this.

```
public String wordsToCorrect (String word)
        {
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            StringBuilder sb;
            String[] bro =new String[5];
            bro [0] = "bros";
            bro [1] = "bro";
            bro [2] = "bros";
            bro [3] = "broda";
            bro [4] = "brother";
            String[] brother = bro;
            String[] si = new String[6];
            si [0] = "sis";
            si [1] = "sister";
            si [2] = "sista";
            si [3] = "6sta";
            si [4] = "sisy";
            si [5] = "sissy";
            String[] sister = si;
            for ( int i=0;i < brother.length;i ++ )
                {
                    if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(word, brother [i]) )
                        {
                            StrBuilder replace = new StrBuilder();
                            replace.append(word);
                            replace.append(" ");
                            replace.replaceAll(brother [i], "brother");
                            return replace.toString();
                        }
                }

            for ( int i= 0;i < sister.length;i++   )
                {
                    if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(word, sister [i]) )
                        {
                            StrBuilder replace = new StrBuilder();
                            replace.append(word);
                            replace.append(" ");
                            replace.replaceAll(sister [i], "sister");
                            return replace.toString();

                        }
                }
```

Comment: replace  for ( int i= 0;i < sister.length;i   )  by    for ( int i= 0;i < sister.length;i++)

Comment: you put return as soon loop get the condition. What do you want in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String wordsToCorrect (String word)
{
    StringBuilder sb;
    String[] bro =new String[5];
    bro [0] = "bros";
    bro [1] = "bro";
    bro [2] = "bros";
    bro [3] = "broda";
    bro [4] = "brother";
    String[] brother = bro;
    String[] si = new String[6];
    si [0] = "sis";
    si [1] = "sister";
    si [2] = "sista";
    si [3] = "6sta";
    si [4] = "sisy";
    si [5] = "sissy";

    List<String> broList = Arrays.asList(bro);
    List<String> sisList = Arrays.asList(si);
    String[] words = word.split("\\s");
    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        String singleWord = words[i];
        if(broList.contains(singleWord.toLowerCase())){
            words[i] = "brother";
        }else if(sisList.contains(singleWord.toLowerCase())){
            words[i] = "sister";
        }
    }
    return String.join(" ", words);
}
```

EDIT: added explanation

Your problem is no just the loop ending. If you manage to continue with your loop you can sustitute bro in the word "brother" so you get "brotherther". With my code you first split by space, so you get every word isolated and then match it with the ones you are looking for. I use the lists as it's simpler to use contains. Also you are not needing the ignoreCase as you are doing the .toLower() (I prefer it on the contains argument as this doesn't change the upperCases on the original String).

This code works good with any String that uses spaces as separator. If you need to work also with line breaks you should need to modify the split part and manage to maintain the separators maybe with an approach similar to your initial.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the StrBuilder inside the loop and get it initialized each time, moreover the return will exit from the loop/method and the call is been sent back to the calling place.

Try the below code

```
          StrBuilder replace = new StrBuilder();                
          for ( int i=0;i < brother.length;i   )
            {
                if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(word, brother [i]) )
                    {

                        replace.append(word);
                        replace.append(" ");
                        replace.replaceAll(brother [i], "brother");

                    }
            }
         return replace.toString(); // This return statement will also exit from the method, so seperate the brother and sister replacement in seperate methods/calls
```

---

Put this in a seperate method

```
        StrBuilder replace1 = new StrBuilder();
        for ( int i= 0;i < sister.length;i   )
            {
                if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(word, sister [i]) )
                    {

                        replace1.append(word);
                        replace1.append(" ");
                        replace1.replaceAll(sister [i], "sister");


                    }
            }
             return replace1.toString();
```

Comment: This approach has a problem, even if it solves the loop ending: it tries to replace each occurrence in the whole text. This means that if yo provide "brother" it will find "bro" and the resulting word will be "brotherther", It depends on the array order, but even if "brother" goes before than "bro" in the array, it will also replace "brother" to "brother" and then "brother" to "brotherther",

Comment: Thanks man! This is exactly what i'm looking for. Everything you said about my code is correct it does indeed return "brotherther",thanks again for helping out.@Rubasace

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues in this code: 1) cycle variable doesn't increment, 2) "replace" reinitializes every cycle run, 3) return ends your method. So try this:

```
            StrBuilder replace = new StrBuilder();                
            for (int i=0;i < brother.length;i++) {
                if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(word, brother [i])) {
                        replace.append(word);
                        replace.append(" ");
                        replace.replaceAll(brother [i], "brother");
                 }
            }
            return replace.toString();
```

Then do the same changes for the second cycle and make it a separate method.

Comment: same problem as @Clement Amarnath's solution, even if it also solves the loop ending.